# Are EM wave reflections and Eddy Currents UN-related concepts?

Tags: electromagnetism

When an EM wave is reflected from a PEC (Perfect Electric Conductor) a couple things are apparently true:

1. There is a surface current density equal to the tangential component
   of the magnetic field, and the normal component of the field is 0.
2. There is a charge density equal to the normal component of the
   electric field, and the tangential component of the field is 0.

Because the PEC will not allow an electric field to exist internally, which means there can be no induced current internally, then it seems that you can't have any magnetic induction and you don't have any eddy currents.  If this is true then:

1. What causes the surface current to exist?  Is this current transported by the wave?  Does that mean that in ampere's, $\nabla\times B = \mu (J + \epsilon jwE)$, the conduction current $J$ is both the current of the 'source' (maybe a solenoid or something) and is inseparably combined with the surface current on a PEC?
2. What happens as the material becomes slightly resistive.  Do eddy currents begin to form then?
3. Would the surface current be in phase with the applied magnetic field while the eddy currents are out of phase (both because of the time derivative in faraday's law as well as the change in phase caused by varying speed of light)?
4. What's the regime (of conductivity and/or frequency) where one effect dominates the other?

Comment: Please explain obscure acronyms such as PEC on first use.

Comment: [Skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) may answer some of your questions.